# aws cdk pipelines: pass synthesized CloudFormation template name and configuration files to DeployCdkStackAction

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I am using the `pipelines` module to deploy an AWS application across multiple accounts. At first, I followed the documentation and the recommended approach of implementing a Stage using the `add_application_stage` method:

```
pipeline.add_application_stage(
    FoundationsStage(
        self,
        "stage_id",
        env=Environment(account="111111111111", region="us-east-1"),
    )
)
```

This approach works well but is not flexible enough as it does not allow the user to pass an IAM role when deploying the infrastructure in the child account (and instead relies on a default CDK role created at bootstrap).

As an alternative, I tried to use the [`DeployCdkStackAction`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.pipelines/DeployCdkStackAction.html) construct which does take an IAM role as a parameter. However, it also requires the user to pass a path to both the synthesized CloudFormation template and configuration files:

```
DeployCdkStackAction(
    action_role=...,
    template_path=..., # how to obtain this?
    template_configuration_path=..., # and this?
)
```

I don't know how to obtain these and could not find it in the documentation. I believe it should be possible given that `add_application_stage` does essentially the same thing by running a `DeployCdkStackAction` under the hood? I have tried to obtain the information from the passed CodePipeline `Artifact` but it only returns a Token which would only be solved at deployment time.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this after some digging. CDK IAM roles are determined from the synthesizer passed to stacks and can be customized. More details on boostrapping synthesizers [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html#bootstrapping-custom-synth)

For instance:

```
MyStack(
    self,
    "my_id",
    synthesizer=DefaultStackSynthesizer(
        deploy_role_arn="arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/cdk-${Qualifier}-deploy-my-role-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}",
        cloud_formation_execution_role="arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/cdk-${Qualifier}-cfn-my-exec-role-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}",  # noqa
    ),
)
```